# What is the best way of organizing and implementing page specific CSS and JavaScript in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Question 1:
I've heard of creating div class' to cater to certain areas of the HTML but is there another way out there? Here's a link that I found related to what I mean.

http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/

Question 2:
Is there a way in order for me to organize my CSS and JavaScripts in my asset folder in the rails app IN SPECIFIC FOLDERS while accessing the asset pipeline benefits?
Eg.

Normal way:
assets

images(under assets)

stylesheets(under assets)
mycss1 CSS scss
mycss2 CSS scss
mycss3 CSS scss

javascripts(under assets)
myjava1 js
myjava2 js
myjava custom js

The Idea:
assets

images(under assets)

stylesheets(under assets)
myview(this is a subfolder of the stylesheets folder)
mycss1 CSS scss
mycss2 CSS scss
homepage(subfolder)
mycss3 CSS scss

javascripts(under assets)
myview(subfolder of javascripts)
myjava1 js
homepage(subfolder)
myjava2 js
myjava2 custom js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to add your custom folders under the assets directory, put some files with specific CSS and JS and use them whenever you need it.

To achieve this you should include those files somewhere. By default, you have an appplication layout which includes application.js and application.css files which includes the rest of the related files. Those files known as manifest files and they are using sprockets gem to handle dependencies, preprocessing, compressing and other stuff ([you can read more about it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)). You can change the assets folder using `config.assets.prefix` or add new paths to look up for sprockets using `config.assets.paths` (This might be what you are looking for. [Further reading here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets))

Comment: @CatherineAustria, glad to see it! Do not hesitate to upvote a useful answers ; )